# Переключение текста с помощью радиокнопок

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, css-animation

Как сделать переключение текста с помощью радиокнопок на css, как на примере[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Или нужно будет подклюать JS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
input {
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  margin-right: 1em;
}

div {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: none;
}

:checked + * + * + * {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="r" checked />
<input type="radio" name="r" />
<input type="radio" name="r" />

<div>Переключение текста с помощью радиокнопок</div>
<div>Как сделать переключение текста с помощью радиокнопок на css, как на примере Как сделать переключение текста с помощью радиокнопок на css, как на примере Как сделать переключение текста с помощью радиокнопок на css, как на примере Как сделать переключение текста с помощью радиокнопок на css, как на примере</div>
<div>Или нужно будет подклюать JS?</div>
```

Comment: Почему при нажатии на радиокнопки новый текст добавляется, но старый не пропадает?

Comment: @Knurl360259, вероятно, ты забыл им одинаковый name задать.

Comment: Да так и есть действительно забыл

Answer (score 5):

В самом общем виде как-то так:

```css
p {
  display: none;
}
#one:checked ~ #text1,
#two:checked ~ #text2,
#three:checked ~ #text3{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="one" />
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="two" />
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="three" />

<p id="text1">Текст 1</p>
<p id="text2">Текст 2</p>
<p id="text3">Текст 3</p>
```